# Integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt d]$ when $d≡1 \bmod 4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the integral closure is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2}]$. But how to prove this? Is it possible to prove it without using norm and trace?

Comment: Do you have the abstract algebra text by Dummitt and Foote? They outline a proof of this in that book. I believe they use norm and trace though...

Comment: Yes. It has been a while since I have looked in there, but it is an example I believe. It is definitely in there.

Comment: First off, do you see why $(1+\sqrt{d})/2$ is an algebraic integer? Once you've seen that, you just need to show that all integers in that field lie in that ring. In other words, any solution to a monic quadratic equation that has a "$\sqrt{d}$" appear must be in that ring. This is actually really easy, just by peaking at the quadratic formula. (In fact, showing that the ring of integers is *smaller* than this when $d\equiv 3$ is really the hard part of the classification.)

Comment: As an example of why something like this should be expected, notice that $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_3] = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$, where $\zeta_3 = \frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a primitive third root of unity, and surely $\zeta_3$ is integral.

Comment: What's wrong with using the norm and trace?